# C++ Variadic parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I am designing a convenient config object which will load config values from a file.  In order to make sure there are sane defaults, the programmer can state for each kind of value what type it is, and a default value.  That way, the config file can be checked and any incorrect can be immediately found.  For example, consider the following config file httpd.conf:

```
port    8080
htdocs  ROOT
prelude true
```

and a config object in main:

```
int main() {
  Config conf("httpd.conf",
    "port", Config::INT, 80,
    "htdocs", Config::STRING, "default/",
    "preload", Config::BOOLEAN, false);
```

The above code would load the file and verify that port is in fact an integer,
it would load htdocs , and it would find that "prelude" in the file does not match any registered value in the config, and emit an error:

line 3: undefined configuration item "prelude"

I could implement the above with an old C variadic parameters, but those are not typesafe.  Is there any way to do it with the new C++ variadic parameters? The examples I have seen are all monotyped. Here I have triples of values.

I would like to design something that is easy to write in a single large call, but that is typesafe.

Comment: "preload" or "prelude"?

Comment: It can be done with variadic templates. It's not trivial though.

Comment: I think [Boost's program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html) already covers all that.

Comment: As for your question on other ways to do it, you could do it with chained calls. Like `Config conf("httpd.conf"); conf.param("port", Config::INT, 80).param("htdocs", Config::STRING, "default/").param("preload", Config::BOOLEAN, false);`

Comment: Would grouping the arguments into constructors for temporary objects be acceptable? Like so: (i.e. `conf("xx", Param("port", Config::INT, 80), Param("htdocs", Config::STRING, "default/"),`...

Comment: @Joachim +1 though it's UGLY, like Java append in StringBuilder.

Comment: @Joachim, the "typo" is an error in the file caught by the code.
the option is "preload" but if you type "prelude" in the config file, it can catch the error.  That was the intention

Answer (score 3):

Without using variadic templates or functions and avoiding type elision you might do:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Configuration
{
    public:
    Configuration(const std::string& resource)
    // Initialize the resources: Program options, environment variables, files
    {}

    /// Get a raw configuration value for a key.
    /// Reurns true if the key exists
    bool get_raw(const std::string key, std::string& result) const {
        // Find the key in supplied resources and set the result string
        // trimming leading and trailing spaces
        return false;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T get(const std::string key) const;

    template <typename T>
    T get(const std::string key, const T& default_value) const;
};

template <typename T>
T Configuration::get(const std::string key) const {
    std::string str;
    if( ! get_raw(key, str)) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Key");
    else {
        T result;
        std::istringstream is(str);
        is.unsetf(std::ios_base::basefield);
        is >> result;
        if( ! is.eof() || is.fail()) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Value");
        return result;
    }
}

template <typename T>
T Configuration::get(const std::string key, const T& default_value) const {
    std::string str;
    // There might be a dilemma - is a non existing key an error?
    if( ! get_raw(key, str)) return default_value;
    else if(str.empty()) return default_value;
    else {
        T result;
        std::istringstream is(str);
        is.unsetf(std::ios_base::basefield);
        is >> result;
        if( ! is.eof() || is.fail()) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Value");
        return result;
    }
}


// Usage
struct HttpConfiguration : public Configuration
{
    unsigned port;
    std::string htdocs;
    bool preload;

    HttpConfiguration()
    :   Configuration("httpd.conf"),
        port(get<unsigned>("port", 80)),
        htdocs(get<std::string>("htdocs", "default/")),
        preload(get<bool>("prelude", false)) // typo here
    {}
};
```

Note: The class configuration can be anything managing configuration sources (have a look at Boost, POCO, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started if you want to use variadic templates:

```
template <class T>
struct Param {
  using Type = T;
  std::string name_;
  T default_value_;
};

template <class T>
auto MakeParam(std::string name, T default_value) -> Param<T> {
  return {name, default_value};
}

template <class T, class... Args>
auto ReadParams(Param<T> p, Args... args) -> void {
  ReadParams(p);
  ReadParams(args...);
}

template <class T>
auto ReadParams(Param<T> p) -> void {
  // here you can read from file
  cout << "param: '" << p.name_ << "' type: '"
       << typeid(typename Param<T>::Type).name() << "' defval: '"
       << p.default_value_ << "'" << endl;
}

int main() {
  ReadParams(MakeParam("param1", 0), MakeParam("param2", true),
             MakeParam("param3", "c-string"),
             MakeParam("param4", std::string{"c++str"}));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually think the other solution without variadic parameters is better and more consise, even though this one is technically exactly what I asked for....